# Reverse connection from munin client to server through ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, munin

I can usually figure this out, but I feel like I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

I have a munin server, and clients. It works fine. They are all located on a private network. I would like to now forget the munin server I have, and instead, use a munin server that is sitting on the internet. The server on the internet accepts ssh connections. I would therefore think that I can create an ssh tunnel from the client to the server, and then have the server query the munin client. So basically:

remoteclient-----router----[internet]----server

So far, I have read [this promising question](https://serverfault.com/questions/379600/ssh-tunneling-for-munin#379653). It has not worked out. I have also read [this in the FAQ](https://munin-monitoring.org/faq), but I am pretty sure after reading the FAQ several times that the FAQ is specifically stating that the *server* will initiate an ssh connection to the *client*.

I am trying to do the opposite.

I am using this on the client:

```
 ssh -L 49499:localhost:4949 -f  number9@myserver.com -p 2222 -N
```

(yes, ssh listens on 2222)

And on the client munin config I have:

```
[remoteclient]
    address 127.0.0.1
    port 49499
    use_node_name yes
```

On the server, it is failing with:

```
starting work in 6794 for remoteclient/127.0.0.1:49499
[FATAL] Socket read from remoteclient failed.  Terminating process. at /usr/share/perl5/Munin/Master/UpdateWorker.pm line 254.
```

Again, I think what I am trying to do is the reverse of the other FAQ/items that I am reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a [RemoteForward](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#RemoteForward) kind of tunnel rather than a [LocalForward](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#LocalForward) kind.

> `RemoteForward`
>
> Specifies that **a TCP port on the remote machine** be forwarded over the
> secure channel.

So on the client:

> ```
> ssh -L 49499:localhost:4949 -f  number9@myserver.com -p 2222 -N
> ```

should simply be replaced with:

```
ssh -R 49499:localhost:4949 -f  number9@myserver.com -p 2222 -N
```

That way, the remote machine: the server, will have a port opened on its localhost which will forward back through the tunnel traffic to client's localhost (ie: still stay on the client at the exit of the tunnel).

Comment: I tried that initially with no luck. I actually did exactly what you said, with no luck. Same error. I think an interesting thing is this: on the client it seems to be working (e.g. ssh returns no errors) On the server, however, netstat shows no tunnel... would it only show up as 2222?

Comment: Yup, sometimes we make mistakes. This time, the client said "connect_to localhost port 4949: failed.". Hrm, I added host 127.0.0.1 to munin-node.conf, still no luck. I added host * to munin-node.conf, now it works. Apparently, I was denying my ssh all along. Thanks for the input. -R is the way to go